# How to hide the PHP file extension using WampServer and .htacess file?

Tags: windows-7, wamp, htaccess, httpd, mod-rewrite

I just installed WampServer on Windows7 and uncommented **mod_rewrite** and set **AllowOverride** to *All* in the httpd.config file.

I created an .htacess file and placed it in the root folder with the following statement:

```
options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I then created **test1.php** file and placed it in the same folder as the *.htacess* file. However, I still must provide the extension on the browser to view the file. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

This `.htaccess` file worked for me:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

You may also want to make sure that `mod_rewrite.so` is enabled in Apache's `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: You saved me sir, htaccess was turned on, but not working correctly, I was redirecting all "/file" to "index.php?file=file.php", but when I accessed "/something" it was the same as if I was accessing "/something.php", not sure why, but "Options -MultiViews" made it run correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if mod_rewrite is run by apache?

- Click on the WampServer icon, select Apache, Apache modules
- Scroll down until you see 'Rewrite_Module'
- If there is no check mark before Rewrite_Module click on it to enable it.

Now things should work (I am not sure if you have to restart the Apache service, just try)